# Unknown Type Name error in OS' Mach Library

Tags: xcode, types, struct, xcode4.3

I'm getting the following:

```
Unknown type name 'mach_port_context_t'
```

As a compiler error when I'm trying to build my XCode project.  It points to `message.h`, which is in the `iPhoneSimulator5.1/usr/include/mach/` folder.

It doesn't show up when I build for the device.  (I'm testing in simulator b/c I need to debug some files)
I'm definitely not doing any crazy threading or port stuff (outside of `NSOperation`), so I'm not sure what the issue for the mach is...

`mach_port_context_t` has no definition in message.h file... others such as `audit_token_t` and `security_token_t` do:

```
typedef struct 
{
  mach_msg_trailer_type_t   msgh_trailer_type;
  mach_msg_trailer_size_t   msgh_trailer_size;
  mach_port_seqno_t     msgh_seqno;
  security_token_t      msgh_sender; // <-- defined (ex. below)
  audit_token_t         msgh_audit; //<-- defined (ex. below)
  mach_port_context_t       msgh_context; //<-- Error Here
} mach_msg_context_trailer_t;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int          val[8];
} audit_token_t;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int          val[2];
} security_token_t;
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clear project **"User Header Search Path"**